# Automatic merge in bitbucket after successful jenkins build

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket

**Current Setup**

I use the Bitpucket multipipeline script for Bitbucket,
When a Pull Request is created the jenkins build is triggered

my Jenkins pipeline is currently as follows (for merges to development branch):

1. checkout merged code
2. build + run tests
3. do some sonarqube analysis
4. block if quality gate fails
   5a. check into nexus
   5b) (if it is a software to release, copy it to the server and roll it out automatically to the test server)

**What I want**

The final step I want is to automatically merge and close the PR when jenkins has approved. (In a later stage i want this only to happen on PR's from features to development, we will have a different procedure for release/production PR's).

I see two possible solutions, either bitbucket has something built in so I can call the merge for the given PR from jenkins with a plugin in jenkins/add it to the Jenkinsfile

or I have a Bitbucket plugin to automatically finalize the merge when jenkins approves (somehow)

If you need any more information i will gladly provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i found a plugin that does exactly what i want, it costs 10$ atm in the bitbucket store, but i can set an automerge after at least 1 successful build and then configured the bitbucket notifier to approve the build at the end.

If anyone else struggles with this the plugin in bitbucket is called workzone, the confirmation of the build can easily be done with

```
stage("merge PullRequest to Dev") {
    currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'   
    notifyBitbucket commitSha1: '', considerUnstableAsSuccess: false, credentialsId: 'pw_bb', disableInprogressNotification: true, ignoreUnverifiedSSLPeer: false, includeBuildNumberInKey: false, prependParentProjectKey: false, projectKey: '', stashServerBaseUrl: 'https://mybbserver'
}
```